# How to override method once for all UIKIt

Tags: swift4, viper-architecture

I want to write iOS application based on VIPER architecture, so my goal is to get segue from router. I call `view.performSegue(withIdentifier: sender:)` from router and as sender i put closure that returns me a segue.

I want to override method `prepare(for: sender:)` for all view controllers in `UIKit`.

Actually I understand, that I can inherit from all classes, that have that method, and override it, but I want to do it once, for example in protocol, and after use it everywhere.

Any suggestions?

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let closure = sender as? (UIStoryboardSegue) -> (){
        closure(segue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a BasicViewController which implement your override prepare function and use this when create another viewControllers.